# Getting IndexPath Item in TableView Embedded in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a TableView that is embedded into a CollectionView, and I am trying to show relevant data in the TableView that corresponds to the correct CollectionViewCell or IndexPath Item. I tried assigning tag as such: `cell.tableView.tag = indexPath.item` but it seems to be problematic.

I tried `print(tableView.tag)` in my collectionViewCell and it printed 
`2 1 0 3 4 5`
but I have 7 collectionViewCells in total so the last tag isn't printing for some reason.

My collectionView is embedded in another TableView already, below is the code in the MasterTableViewCell.swift:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        if diningIndexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell: FoodCourtCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "foodCourtCell", for: indexPath) as! FoodCourtCollectionViewCell

            cell.tableView?.register(UINib(nibName: "RestaurantTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "restaurantCell")


            cell.tableView.tag = indexPath.item

            //...

            return cell
      }
}
```

In the customCollectionViewCell.swift, I have this code for my tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: RestaurantTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "restaurantCell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantTableViewCell

        print(tableView.tag)

        let currentRestaurant = foodCourts[tableView.tag].childLocations[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = currentRestaurant.name

        //...

        return cell
    }
```

Is there any way to fix this, or are there other ways to achieve what I want to do? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you post your code. it would be much easier to help

Comment: where are you printing from?

Comment: Just added the code. I printed from the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting these entities is always a pain especially when you need to access indexPaths of items later. If if get your problem correctly. One of the solutions I suggest is to store a map (dictionary) of your paths. For a fast access to them. Here's an example of how I managed this in a similar situation:

```
typealias CollectionIndexPath = IndexPath
typealias TableIndexPath = IndexPath
var indexMap: [CollectionIndexPath: TableIndexPath] = [:]
```

Now when you need to access some of the items or configure it.

```
func cellForItemAtIndexPath { ... } {
     let cell = { ... }

     let cellPath = indexPath
     let tablePath = indexMap[cellPath]
     let foodCourtForCell = foodCourts[cellPath.item]
     let childLocationsForTableView = foodCourtForCell.childLocations

     cell.configureWith(court: foodCourtForCell, locations: childLocations)
```

Now you can manage all the data related to this nested monster from the outside.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I'm not too sure about how I would populate the indexMap.